# Content of button in ItemsControl bound to List not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a button in my view like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}" Content="{Binding toDelete, Converter={StaticResource DeleteButtonContentConverter}}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
```

That is not updating when toDelete changes. I know that my converter works because the text displays correctly when the view is first loaded (and when I hard code it to make sure that it works both ways). I assume that the GUI is being notified of the List changing because my logging it turning up in the logs but I am not sure how to test the notification directly:

```
    private List<AppList> _appList;
    public List<AppList> appList
    {
        get { return _appList; }
        set { Set(ref _appList, value); Log.Debug("appList changed"); }
    }
```

I assume that the problem is being caused by the button being part of a list that is bound to an ItemsControl but I cannot work out how to update a property of an object in a List.

As a test, I have created an event which is fired when the button is clicked (clicking should change the content of the button itself) and tried using RaisePropertyChanged to notify of a change to the List and to the property bound to Content itself. Neither worked.

In case it helps the WPF for the ItemsControl is:

```
    <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ScrollviewerStyle}" Grid.Row="2">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding appList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlBorderStyle}">
                        <Grid Width="540">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="255"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Content="Alias:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding alias, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Content="Path:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding path, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="255" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}" Content="{Binding toDelete, Converter={StaticResource DeleteButtonContentConverter}}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Does the AppList class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppList` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever the `toDelete` property is set to a new value.

Then the converter should get invoked each time the property is set, and the `Content` of the `Button` should be set to whatever the converter returns.

Comment: I implemented ObservableObject instead because I am using MVVM Light and it implements INotifyPropertyChanged, otherwise, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!